# Reorganize php array to erase double entries and merge the others

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'm facing to a problem :
I'm given a json entry which is organized like that :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [libelle] => Emploi
            [sousLibelle] => Réhabilitation professionnelle
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [libelle] => Emploi
            [sousLibelle] => Formations et aides à l'emploi
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [libelle] => Emploi
            [sousLibelle] => Emploi
        )
}
```

What I need to do is that :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [libelle] => Emploi
            [sousLibelle][0] => Réhabilitation professionnelle
            [sousLibelle][1] => Formations et aides à l'emploi
            [sousLibelle][2] => Emploi
        )
)
```

I'm a bit lost here, some help would be nice.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, the following loop is what you wish to do.

It will create a new array with the 'libelle' value as the key, and then remove duplicates.

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
    $new_arr[$val['libelle']][] = $val['sousLibelle'];
}
$new_arr = array_unique($new_arr);
```

**Edit:** Just a side note, `json_decode` for converting the array to a PHP array from a JSON array, and `json_encode` if you're producing the results back in a JSON array.

Comment: This works perfectly. Was a bit tricky to me. In the end, no need to use array_unique because $array contains others 'libelle' with 'sousLibelle'. Thanks to you all for helping me out ;)

Answer (score 1):

So for adding a new `$key=>$value` to your `$result` object, the following rules apply:

- If `$result[$key]` does not exist yet, create it and set it to `$value`.
- If `$result[$key]` exists and is an array, check if `$value` is in it. If not, add it (`$result[$key][] = $value`).
- If `$result[$key]` exists but is not an array, check if it is equal to `$value`. If not, create a new array with the original `$result[$key]` and the new value `$value` and assign it.

Did I get this correctly? Because the above translates quite straightforwardly into PHP. I could write it out for you, but I will leave the actual work to you :)

Comment: Instead of running a check to see if the $value is in the array each time, you could use `array_unique` at the end.

Comment: Yes, then you just need to convert it back if it turns out that the array just has one element afterwards. At least, I understand that Neovea does not want arrays with a single element, so either the single unique value or an array with all unique values.

Comment: Did OP state he didn't want single elements?

Comment: He wants `array( "libelle" => "Emploi", "sousLibelle" => array( "Réhabilitation professionnelle", "Formations et aides à l'emploi", "Emploi")` as far as I understood.

Comment: But if there was only one 'sousLibelle', it would go into an array anyway? Unless he wanted a single entry as a string as opposed to a single value array. Although for processing I'm sure it would work out easier to have a standard format.

Comment: Yep, that's the part that's not clear to me. We'll see if he gets back to us :)